# Is server alive app

Tags: server, 12.10, software-recommendation, administration

I'm just wondering, is there an Ubuntu program to check if certain IP's are up ?

I have a few servers and i'm searching for a small program\app\indicator to ping\telnet\tcp-connect my servers and tell me by notification or email if they are up or down.

Comment: take a look at "nagios" its even in the repositories, it might be more than what you want since its a full flagged IT server monitor solution

Comment: Isn't there a small application for this ?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's anything out there, but it can easily be done in a bash script or python script, since this is something i might find usefull myself, ill look into making one later on if i have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) may be an option for you as it is designed to keep tabs on servers and even the health of services running on those servers.

It can be configured to email you when server/service state changes. Other actions can also be scripted for when events occur (mine sends a text to my phone).

There are a number of application that can connect to nagios such as [nagstamon](http://nagstamon.ifw-dresden.de/)  (note: I haven't used this my self) and display status on your computer.

[Packages for nagios](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nagios3) are available in the standard Ubuntu repos

Comment: Isn't there a small application for this ?